# Open tab in existing IE instance

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

```
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
```

Everytime i open a new website with this object(ie every time when script runs) it is opened in a new IE window and i don't want it to do that. I want it to be opened in a new tab but that too in a previously opened IE window. I want to reuse this object when the script runs next time. I don't want to create a new object

So is there any way like to check for the instances of internet explorer and to reuse its instance ???

**I tried this as a solution:**

First you have to attach to the already running Internet Explorer instance:

```
$ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() `
    | ? { $_.Name -eq "Windows Internet Explorer" }
```

Then you Navigate to the new URL. Where that URL is opened is controlled via the Flags parameter:

```
$ie.Navigate("http://www.google.com/", 2048)
```

but am not able to call `navigate` method on this newly created object `$ie`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Start-Process` to open the URL. If a browser window is already open, it will open as a tab.

```
Start-Process 'http://www.microsoft.com'
```

Comment: This assumes that Internet Explorer is the default web browser.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `Start-Process` just sends the URL to whatever the default browser is on the system. It works for me with Firefox as my default browser.

Comment: Yes, it does open in the default browser, Chrome, FF, IE or whatever. However the question was focused on IE, so I just wanted to point out that IE has to be set to the default browser.

Comment: You are correct. I interpreted your first comment to mean it only worked if IE is the default browser.

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation of what the downvoter doesn't like about this answer. I know it won't happen, but still...

Answer (score 10):

First you have to attach to the already running Internet Explorer instance:

```
$ie = (New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").Windows() |
      Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Windows Internet Explorer" }
```

Then you [`Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the new URL. Where that URL is opened is controlled via the [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) parameter:

```
$ie.Navigate("http://www.google.com/", 2048)
```

**Edit:** In case 2 or more IE instances are running (additional tabs count as additional instances as well) the enumeration will return an array, so you have to select a particular instance from the array:

```
$ie[0].Navigate("http://www.google.com/", 2048)
```

Comment: **but m not able to call navigate method on this newly created object,ie. on $ie**

Comment: The IE object is not newly created. How exactly are you "not able to call the `Navigate` method"? Do you get an error? Does the first command return an object at all? What is the output of `$ie.GetType()` and `$ie | Get-Member`?

Comment: the first command was successful and it returned the object of the same kind, i already checked it with get-member, everything looks to be fine with the object creation but still m not able to call navigate function, it shows an error which is given below: 
Method invocation failed because [System.Objec At line:1 char:14 + $ie3.navigate <<<< ("www.google.com") + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: the first command was successful and it returned the object of the same kind, i already checked it with get-member, everything looks to be fine with the object creation but still m not able to call navigate function, it shows an error which is given below: 

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'navigate'.
At line:1 char:14
+ $ie3.navigate <<<< ("www.google.com")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: <navigate:string>[], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: i checked the type of both the objects and it appeared to be of different types:

the **newly created** was of **type** **Object[]** and with a **base type** of **System.Array**. And the one which was created using without callinig window() method (that is the one which should be created) was of **type** **_ComObject** and with a **base** of **System.MarshalByRefObject**

Comment: Use `$ie[0].Navigate(...)`. Apparently you have more than one IE instance running, so the enumeration returns an array instead of a single object.

Comment: **hey yaa, thankzzzz mate, it worked, thanxx a lot :) :) :) :) :)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if Internet Explorer is not your default browser:

```
Function Open-IETabs {
    param (
        [string[]]$Url
    )
    begin {
        $Ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
    }
    process {
        foreach ($Link in $Url) {
            $Ie.Navigate2($Link, 0x1000)
        }
    }
    end {
        $Ie.Visible = $true
    } 
}
```

I found this on [PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/14043/26814.aspx)