# Open tabs in internet explorer with cmd

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, tabs, cmd

I want to make a cmd batch file that opens 3 tabs in internet explorer window
Doesnt matter to me if there is already internet explorer window open or not
I have this commant, but it opens the tabs in chrome (my default browser, dont want to change it..)

```
START /d iexplore.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://marathon:7040/console/jsp/login/j_security_check?j_username=wc&j_password=12345"
START /d iexplore.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://sparta:7040/console/jsp/login/j_security_check?j_username=wc&j_password=12345"
START /d iexplore.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://sparta:7040/console/jsp/login/j_security_check?j_username=wc&j_password=12345"
```

Help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it work in IE! with VB script!! save this in .vbs file:

```
Const navOpenInBackgroundTab = &H1000

site1 = "(write your site here)"
site2 = "(write your site here)"
site3 = "(write your site here)"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate2 site1
oIE.Navigate2 site2,navOpenInBackgroundTab
oIE.Navigate2 site3,navOpenInBackgroundTab

Set oIE = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

I have provided some code for .bat files that should achieve the functionality you are looking for.

To use: copy the code to a Notepad window and save as MyFile.bat or some other filename ending in .bat and double-click the file to run.

To open Internet Explorer with 1 window and 3 separate tabs:

```
:: n pings take n-1 seconds
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
```

To open Internet Explorer with 1 window and 3 separate tabs (alternative):

```
:: timeout n lasts between n-1 and n seconds
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
timeout 2
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
timeout 2
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
```

To open Internet Explorer with 3 separate windows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the timeout commands? AFAIK there is no delay required. And why do you use ping in the first example?

Comment: Without small delays (e.g. via `ping`/`timeout`), web pages may open in the wrong order, some might not open at all. Chrome/Edge/Firefox accept space-separated URLs, to instantly open multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://marathon:7040/console/jsp/login/j_security_check?j_username=wc&j_password=12345"
```

?

`/d` switch is for the starting directory (which I think is not relevant in your case).The first parameter is the title which in your case will be `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"`  and for the link left the default program as the open program is not really pointed.

Comment: Tested it, but it opens 3 diffrent windows of internet explorer. I wanted to open one internet explorer window with 3 diffrent tabs

Comment: @Erez - check your internet explorer settings -> http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/internet-explorer-is-opening-new-windows-instead/d18f1b43-e79e-40a4-ac5f-d1b53098d243

Comment: Not working. your code open 3 diffrent windows, not tabs. Tested on 2 computers, with IE9 and IE11

Comment: @Erez - try without `start` command only `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "link"`

Comment: Thanks, but still opens 3 windows instead of tabs

Comment: @Erez then you have to try with vbscript/jscript or powershell -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544839/powershell-open-tab-in-existing-ie-instance  ; http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1721921

Answer (score 0):

This uses a hybrid batch file (save with `.cmd` extension). Tested in XP, but you will have to test in your system.

```
@if (@this==@isBatch) @then
@echo off

    rem search internet explorer
   for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('
        reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE" /ve 
        ^|find "REG_"
    ') do for /f "tokens=1,*" %%c in ("%%~b") do set "iexplore=%%d"

    rem Start first window instance 
    start "" "%iexplore%" -new "http://marathon:7040/console/jsp/login/j_security_check?j_username=wc&j_password=12345"
    rem Let internet explorer initialize this instance
    ping -n 6 localhost  > nul

    rem Now, load a new set of addresses into the last opened window
    cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" /url:"http://sparta:7040/console/jsp/login/j_security_check?j_username=wc&j_password=12345"
    cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" /url:"http://sparta:7040/console/jsp/login/j_security_check?j_username=wc&j_password=12345"

    exit /b

@end //== javascript zone ======================================================= 
    // Values to be used in the Navigate() method
    var navOpenInNewTab         = 0x0800
      , navOpenInBackgroundTab  = 0x1000
      , navOpenNewForegroundTab = 0x10000;

    // Retrieve command line arguments
    var url = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("url");

    // Instantiate component to get access to shell
    var shellApplication = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application');

    // Retrieve the last window
    var windows = new Enumerator(shellApplication.Windows());
    var w = null;
    while (!windows.atEnd()){w = windows.item(); windows.moveNext()};

    // If a window is found, use this window to open the url in a new tab, 
    // else create a iexplore instance to load the url
    if (w){
        w.Navigate(url, navOpenInBackgroundTab, '_blank');
    } else {
        with (new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell')){
            Run('"' 
                + RegRead('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\IEXPLORE.EXE\\')
                + '" -new "' + url + '"'
            )
        }
    };
    // Let everything initialize before exit
    WScript.Sleep(500);
```