# Opening a new tab on an existing Internet Explorer (from Command Line)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, browser, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I would like to run a command on the command prompt (in Windows) that will open Internet Explorer with certain perks.

Scenario (starting with no Internet Explorer opened):

- Run "iexplore google.ca" to open google.ca, as a new tab, on Internet Explorer
- Run "iexplore yahoo.ca" again to open yahoo.ca, as a new tab, on the recently opened Internet Explorer

End result should have 2 tabs on one Internet Explorer application/window.

I would like the above behavior but Internet Explorer will just open new windows instead of new tabs when running the iexplore command. I have already tried various command line options and settings.

Java code such as Runtime or ProcessBuilder will be used to execute this command. Any other solutions will be great as well.

Note: I have found a way to get this behavior but it will only work with the default browser. I would specifically like to specify the Internet Explorer browser instead of relying on the default browser. (start /d "" www.google.ca)

Comment: *"I would specifically like to specify the Internet Explorer browser.."*  So glad your software is not installed here.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099153/open-tabs-in-internet-explorer-with-cmd/45808976#45808976

Answer (score 0):

Next `VBScript` could help. Explanation in commented code.

```
' VB Script Document ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441974
' Opens blank page in a new MSIE tab and navigates to the URL if supplied. 
' Usage: ie [URL]
'        if saved as "IE.VBS" somewhere under PATH system environment variable.
'
option explicit
On Error Goto 0
Dim strMyUrl, intWExist, BrowserNavFlag, iRetNav2, objArgs, WshShell, IE, oIE, sTitle

Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
If objArgs.Count > 0 Then
    strMyUrl = objArgs( 0)
Else
    strMyUrl = "about:blank"
End If

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell")
Set IE  = Nothing
Set oIE = Nothing

intWExist = FindIE( strMyUrl, oIE) ' look for MSIE window pointer 

set IE = oIE
iRetNav2 = 0
Select Case intWExist
' Case 3
'   ''' 3 = MSIE window found, URL match, window title match
'   ''' (not implemented yet)
' Case 2
'   ''' 2 = MSIE window found, URL match
Case 1, 2, 3
    ''' 1 = MSIE window found, no URL match
    BrowserNavFlag = navOpenInNewTab ' 2048
    iRetNav2 = IE.Navigate2( strMyUrl, CLng( BrowserNavFlag), "_blank")
Case Else
    ''' 0 = MSIE window not found
    Set IE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application")
    BrowserNavFlag = 1
    iRetNav2 = IE.Navigate( strMyUrl)
End Select

IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
    Wscript.Sleep 100
Wend
While IE.Document.ReadyState <> "complete" '(obsolete?) Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    Wscript.Sleep 100
Wend

sTitle = ""
intWExist = FindIE( strMyUrl, oIE) ' look for MSIE window title
' AppActivate method could fail (no error) if MSIE window runs minimized
'                               off topic for current question (31441974)
If Not sTitle = "" Then WshShell.AppActivate sTitle

Private Function FindIE( ByVal sUrl, ByRef oObj)
' parameters
' sUrl (input)  string
' oObj (output) object
' returns 
' 0 = any MSIE window not found - or found but not accessible   
' 1 = a MSIE window found
' 2 = 1 and address line match
' 3 = 2 and title match (not implemented yet)
    Dim ww, tpnm, tptitle, tpfulln, tpUrl, tpUrlUnencoded
    Dim errNo, errStr, intLoop, intLoopLimit
    Dim iFound : iFound = 0
    Dim shApp    : Set shApp = CreateObject( "Shell.Application")
    With shApp
        For Each ww In .windows
            tpfulln = ww.FullName
            If Instr( 1, Lcase( tpfulln), "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) <> 0 _ 
        and Instr( 1, UCase( tpfulln), "SCODEF:", vbTextCompare) = 0 _ 
        and Instr( 1, UCase( tpfulln), "CREDAT:", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If iFound > 0 Then
                Else
                    Set oObj = ww
                End If
                tptitle = "x x x" : tpUrl = "" : tpUrlUnencoded = ""
                intLoopLimit = 10 ' to look for attributes max. intLoopLimit/10 seconds
                intLoop = 0
                While intLoop < intLoopLimit
                    intLoop = intLoop + 1
                    On Error Resume Next
                    tpnm = typename( ww.document)
                    errNo = Err.Number
                    If errNo <> 0 Then
                        'error if  page not response (yet)' 
                        errStr = "Error # " & CStr( errNo) _
                & " """ & Err.Description & """ 0x" & Hex( errNo)  
                        Wscript.Sleep 100
                    Else
                        iFound = 1
                        intLoopLimit = intLoop  ' end the loop and preserve loop counter
                        tptitle = ww.document.title
                        tpUrl = ww.document.URL
                        tpUrlUnencoded = ww.document.URLUnencoded
                        errStr = tpnm
            sTitle = tptitle
                    End If
                    On Error Goto 0
                Wend
                If Instr( 1, Lcase( tpnm), "htmldocument", vbTextCompare) <> 0 then
                    If Instr( 1, Lcase( tpUrl), Lcase( sUrl), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                        Set oObj = ww
                        iFound = 2
                        ' looking for all matching MSIE URLs 
                        ' this may take considerable time amount
                        ' to speed up script running, uncomment next line "exit for"
                        exit for
                    Else
                    End If 
                End If
            Else
                ' a program reports the same shell.application property as "iexplore.exe"
                ' i.e. "explorer.exe", "HTML preview" in some editors etc.
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Set shApp = Nothing
    FindIE = iFound
End Function
' 
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx
' BrowserNavConstants Enumerated Type
' Contains values used by the IWebBrowser2::Navigate
'                         and IWebBrowser2::Navigate2 methods.
' typedef enum BrowserNavConstants {
Const navOpenInNewWindow      = &h01, _
      navNoHistory            = &h02, _
      navNoReadFromCache      = &h04, _
      navNoWriteToCache       = &h08, _
      navAllowAutosearch      = &h10, _
      navBrowserBar           = &h20, _
      navHyperlink            = &h40, _
      navEnforceRestricted    = &h80, _
      navNewWindowsManaged    = &h0100, _
      navUntrustedForDownload = &h0200, _
      navTrustedForActiveX    = &h0400, _
      navOpenInNewTab         = &h0800, _
      navOpenInBackgroundTab  = &h1000, _
      navKeepWordWheelText    = &h2000, _
      navVirtualTab           = &h4000, _
      navBlockRedirectsXDomain= &h8000, _
      navOpenNewForegroundTab = &h010000
' } BrowserNavConstants;
'
```