# Powershell script IE Automatic Login opens another Login tab

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I have a script for Internet Explorer Login which works fine. But I want to go further because after the first login, Internet Explorer opens a new tab, with another Login form. So $IE.visible = $False does not work for the second tab, which opens automatically, and also I dont know how to give focus to the second tab to input other credentials and also put it on invisible.

```
$variablePass = $variablePass.Text
$username = "testUser"
$username2 = "testUser2"  
$password = "testPass" + $variablePass
$password2 = "testPass2"



$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $false
$ie.Height = 720
$ie.Width = 1280
$ie.navigate("https://mylink.com") 

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 


#This one work fine

$ie.document.getElementById("username").value = "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = "$password" 
$ie.document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click()

# Here comes the problem, after IE reach mylink.com and do the login script, the a new tab pop up with another login form
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value = "$username2" 
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = "$password2"
$ie.document.getElementById("loginBtn").click()
```

So, how do I do the second Login form to work. Preferably in invisible mode, I mean $IE.visible = $False

Comment: You can try to fetch the object of that new tab from array of IE instances and try to make it visible false. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544839/open-tab-in-existing-ie-instance

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to change the configuration of IE to prevent this from happening?

https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/force-ie-to-open-link-in-new-tab/

You could manually configure IE, or use PowerShell to edit the registry to force that specific configuration...