# Powershell script to open multiple url's in ie browser

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer

Been trying to open multiple url's in ie browser through powershell script

Currently my code is working In chrome browser, how can i achive the same in ie explorer

```
$urls=gc "C:actual path of the url folder\url.txt"
foreach($url in $urls){
    start-process chrome.exe $url

}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the part with "chrome.exe" in your code with iexplore and it should work.

---

EDIT:
Since the original solution opened links in multiple windows, I have created an updated script that tries to open all the links in same browser window.

```
$IE = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$urls= gc "FILEPATH"
$count=1
foreach ($url in $urls){
    if ($count -eq 1){
        $IE.navigate($url,1)
    }
    else{
        $IE.navigate($url,2048)
    }
    $count++
}
```

Comment: Its working but i have 2 observations 1.Its not opening in single web browser like chrome. 2.Its not opening all the urls

Comment: @AbhilashPoojary you can look at this post to open url in same InterExplorer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544839/open-tab-in-existing-ie-instance

Comment: @AbhilashPoojary I think I might have found a way of opening the links in a single browser window . Please look at the edit that I made.

Comment: @telsub Thanks for the modifications its working as per my requirement.

Comment: @crappyprog This is great.  We're experiencing multiple sites throwing intermittent 500 errors, so I was able to create a script to open multiple sites in a single shot.  I still have to go through each browser tab to see if the site opened correctly or not.  Is there a way to have PowerShell tell me if one of the tabs throws a 500 error?

Answer (score 7):

I think this can help you :

This next code open with default web browser :

```
$urls = @("https://stackoverflow.com/","https://www.google.com/","https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/02/open-website-from-powershell/")

foreach($url in $urls){
    Start-Process $url
}
```

This next open in iexplorer :

```
$urls = @("https://stackoverflow.com/","https://www.google.com/","https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/02/open-website-from-powershell/")

foreach($url in $urls){
    # Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" $url
    Start-Process iexplore.exe $url
}
```

Look at thoses link : 
https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/02/open-website-from-powershell/

**

- EDIT multi tabs on InternetExplorer :

** 
Note in Internet Explorer the start process doesn't add new Url (at new tab) to existing instance off IE . 
If you want to open all urls in same instance off IExplorer you have to try other code and see thoses post :

[Open tab in existing IE instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544839/open-tab-in-existing-ie-instance)

https://superuser.com/questions/208883/using-powershell-to-open-several-tabs-on-start-up