# Batch file open url in pre-existing window

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer

```
@echo off

start iexplore http://path/generateInfo.php?orderNum=%1
```

This is my extremely basic batch file. The issue is that it can be ran 20 different times on one button click, and I want it to create 20 tabs in IE. This currently creates 20 different IE windows. Any help would be great.

Each run would have a different parameter for my php page.

Comment: See the PowerShell solutions [Open tab in existing IE instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544839/) and [Using PowerShell to open several tabs on start up](https://superuser.com/questions/208883/). A batch file solution is not possible according to [Internet Explorer command line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)) because of there is no option offered by `iexplore.exe` to pass the url to existing instance if there is one for opening it in one more tab and close second instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set the IE browser as a default browser then with the use of the following code you can open the tab in the existing instance of the IE browser.

```
@echo off
start /d "" www.microsoft.com
```

Output:

[image]